# How to change an image on a slide in Latex?

Tags: latex, beamer

In a frame I have two columns. In the first column I display some information using an itemize. When I display a new item I want to change in the second column the image which is displayed. I tried with onslide but it doesn't help me. Here is the code:

```
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}[l]{10cm}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item
                first item
            \item
                second item
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}[r]{2cm}
        \onslide<1> 
        {
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3.5cm]{First.eps}
                \caption[1]{First Image}
            \end{figure}                
        }
        \onslide<2> 
        {
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=3.5cm]{Second.eps}                   
                \caption[2]{Second Image}
            \end{figure}                
        }
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
```

Could you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using \only instead of \onslide.

Otherwise you might want to try something like:

```
\begin{column}[r]{2cm}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics<1>[width=2cm,height=3.5cm]{First.eps}
        \includegraphics<2>[width=2cm,height=3.5cm]{Second.eps}
        \caption<1>{First Image}
        \caption<2>{Second Image}
    \end{figure}                            
\end{column}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Whadya mean "not programming related"? His question is about how to write code in a Turing complete language to achieve a particular output. It's programming all the way.

Comment: While having <1>, <2> alongside \includegraphics works, having \caption<1>, \caption<2> produces a weird output

Answer (score 11):

Just as a small addition.

Instead of

```
\caption<1>{First Image}
\caption<2>{Second Image}
```

use

```
\caption{\only<1>{First Image}\only<2>{Second Image}}
```

This worked fine for me.